# "error: relocation R_386_32 cannot be used against local symbol; recompile with -fPIC" for libjpeg-turbo

Tags: android-ndk

I am trying to replace the [libjpeg-turbo](https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo) version used by [UVCCamera](https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera) with a newer version. After updating some files, I am getting many instances of the following error when building [UVCCamera](https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera):

```
 [system.err] ld: error: relocation R_386_32 cannot be used against local symbol; recompile with -fPIC
 [system.err] >>> defined in ./obj/local/x86/libjpeg-turbo1500_static.a(jfdctflt-3dn.o)
 [system.err] >>> referenced by jni/libjpeg-turbo-1.5.0/simd/jfdctflt-3dn.asm
 [system.err] >>>               jfdctflt-3dn.o:(.text+0xB4) in archive ./obj/local/x86/libjpeg-turbo1500_static.a
```

So, I reverted the project to a previous working version and still failed to build it. I even restored a cloud backup version but still got the same error. I suspect that I messed up the NDK environment at a certain point by accident.

All I need is to make the compilation work and I have no intention to dig into it to do anything. I wonder if anyone could offer me a quick tip to remedy this error.  Where do I add the C flag "-fPIC"?

Comment: Regarding the CFlag, would it be good to try in the Android.mk under libjpeg-turbo-1.5.0 directory in the variable LOCAL_CFLAGS

Comment: @RajatGupta thank you for lending a hand. I added LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fPIC to every Android.mk file that I could find including the one you mentioned, but unfortunately, this did not resolve this.

Comment: Also, maybe is x86 really required for your project, you maybe can consider disabling or commenting out the x86 target?

Comment: I don't know how to do it.  am afraid of breaking anything. For now,  I have got rid of this error by downgrading NDK from 26.1.10909125 to 17.2.4988734